# Use a DC Signal to govern another circuit using AC

Tags: transistors, circuit-design

this is my first post and I am working on a small project where I have two circuits A and B. A is controlled a micro-controller which sends and output of 0V and 5V depending on the conditions. This signal is sent to circuit B.

Suppose B works has a filament lamp connected to it. It turns on when A sends 5V and remains inactive when it sends 0V.

So how do I bridge these two circuits? I have an idea of bridging with a transistor or something. If it's possible do provide the simple circuit diagram.

Thank you.

Comment: You haven't included voltage and current of he lamp, but a relay (or SSR) may be what you want.

Comment: Depending on the current and voltage a TRIAC could also do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZA2AK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Relay board.*

The simplest and safest option for you is to use a relay interface board. A typical wiring schematic is shown in Figure 1.

- Q1 is a transistor used to boost the current from your micro's GPIO (general-purpose input-output pin enough to energise the 5 V relay, RLY1.
- The relay provides electrical isolation between your low voltage circuit and the mains.
- D1 protects the transistor from the inductive kick when the coil is switched off.

[image]

*Figure 2. A typical 4-relay board. Also available in single, double, sixes and eights.*

A few points.

- Keep mains wiring away from the low-voltage wiring.
- Protect the relay and wiring with a suitable fuse.
- Mount the relay module properly so it's not free to move while you're working on it.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!